# How can I print the items of a class in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
    public $dummy = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux');
    public $progr = array('HTML', 'CSS', 'JS', 'PHP');
}
```

I'm trying to print that out: `print_r(MyClass)`, but it outputs *MyClass* and nothing else. I get similiar things with `echo`, `print`, `var_dump` and `var_export`. It seems that they treat `MyClass` as a string, because `echo(test)` outputs *test*.

So, how can I list the items of a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you instantiated it?

What does this output:

```
$m = new MyClass();
print_r($m);
```

Comment: I'm thinking more in classes than in objects hence my use of reflecion... +1 for a simpler solution

Comment: I agree that it's not exactly what the OP was asking about ("So, how can I list the items of a class?"). I suggest this as a simple way to get similar results, though I suppose your answer is the correct one right here.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because both do what I want, but yours are somewhat simpler than @BoltClock's.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) on an instance of your class, and optionally use [`ReflectionProperty`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php) to get the values of the properties as in your instance:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass(new MyClass());

foreach ($rc->getProperties() as $property) {
    printf('%s = %s', $property->getName(), print_r($property->getValue(), true));
}
```

On second thought, if you just want to get the values of an object's properties then [mingos' answer using `print_r(new MyClass());`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839115/how-can-i-print-a-class-in-php/4839133#4839133) works too.

Another thing,

> It seems that they treat `MyClass` as a string, because `echo(test)` outputs *test*.

This is normal: PHP first treats them as constant names, but if it can't find constants defined with those names, then it treats them as unquoted string literals.

Comment: Thanks! `print_r(new MyClass())` seems fine for me – thanks for reminding me to `new` –, but that `ReflectionClass` thingy is nice, too.

Comment: new ReflectionClass("MyClass"); would be more appropriate

Comment: Yeah mine is overkill, I think I need sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it can be helpful to implement the class's __toString magic method as well.  In brief, __toString allows you to specify exactly how an object should behave when it is echoed.  For more information, please see the following:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring

I like to use __toString as a debugging tool, though I'm sure the true potential of the method is significantly more profound :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php
and print_r( );